# SQL Server 2008 : SELECT min(date)

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I'm trying to do a simple select statement but I'm having a hard time doing it.

I have a table with these columns:

```
companyID, CompanyDept, DateAdded
```

I'm trying to do a select statement like this...

```
Select CompanyID, CompanyDept 
where min(dateAdded)
```

So there are multiple dates for `DateAdded` - I'm trying to select the `CompanyDept` and `COmpanyID` by the earliest `DateAdded`.

EDIT: Select CompanyID, CompanyDEpt where dateAdded=MIN so because there might be three or more dates such as 10/1/2015, 11/12/2015, 1/4/2016 -(rows of data i mean) I'm trying to select this date looking at the earliest possible date (10/1/2016)

Comment: Select top 1 CompanyID, CompanyDept from {tablename} order by dateAdded desc

Comment: What should happen with ties?

Comment: @shawnt00 not sure what you mean?

Comment: Can there be more than one with the same date?

Comment: Nope, they are all different in all cases. There is a restriction on how often they can be added. Thanks for inquiry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try just getting the first record using TOP 1 and ordering by date.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CompanyID, CompanyDept
FROM 
    Table
ORDER BY 
    dateAdded
```

Comment: Simple and does the job!

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear what you want but I think is what you are looking for.

```
with sortedResults as
(
    Select CompanyID
        , CompanyDept 
        , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CompanyID, CompanyDept order by dateAdded desc) as RowNum 
    from YourTable
)

select CompanyID
    , CompanyDept
from sortedResults
where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CompanyID, CompanyDept 
FROM TableName 
order by dateadd ASC
```

I assume you want all record ,
not? you want the 1 record which is old or new
for old do ASC and for new do DESC

```
select top (1)* from CompanyID, CompanyDept 
FROM TableName 
order by dateadd ASC
```

if not above read below:
Q.how do you know that earlier date? is there another column name to compare date  with.?

if yes,

```
where dateadd <= that column
order by dateadd ASC
```